# What is the controller used in podcasts section of itunes for navigation in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

what is name of the controller used in podcasts section of itunes app in iphone to navigate between "whats Hot", "top tens", "categories in ". I searched for it but I did not get any thing about this kind of navigation between UIViewControllers http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10. I find that kind of navigation very useful in my app and want to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse my previous answer, misunderstood the question.

Anyway, what you are looking for is the [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

Its not by default a view controller so you will have to write code for it to handle views when its value changes.

Comment: Thanks very much for a prompt response.